# How do I prevent a slicer from interacting with all columns except for one in a dataset using ALLEXCEPT in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, slicers

I'm trying to calculate the 5th percentile value in a measure that gives the number of days that have elapsed since a customer made their last purchase.

I want the output of the 5th percentile measure to be dependent on the range of dates in a slicer.

This is the measure I'm currently using -

```
PERCENTILEX.INC(
    ALLEXCEPT('Master File', 'Master File'[Sale Date II].[Date]),
    [RFM - Recency Value in Days],
    0.05
)
```

The slicer and the measure contain columns and measures that come from the same table, i.e. Master File. I want the measure to only be dependent on the Sale Date II column, which is also used to create the slicer.

However, this measure outputs the same value regardless of the value in the date slicer, which leads me to believe that it is not taking into account the slicer and is calculating the 5th percentile for all date rows in the dataset.

How do I fix this?